# CSS - blur filter stops working after a moment

Tags: html, css, web, blur

When I apply `filter: blur(10px);` to a `body` element, I can see that it is working, but only for a moment, when the website is loading.

When the loading is done, the blur disappears. Why it is like that?
Also, when I set it afterwards with JS it still doesn't work.

Comment: and can you show us this ?

Comment: I don't see any errors here: https://jsfiddle.net/aa66r5r9/. Probably, some of your CSS rules or JS overwrites your blur.

Comment: It's hard to show this (it is done in QtWebEngine, not browser).   
Anyway, I tracked it down. It seems that fullpage.js (a JS lib to scroll pages) screws up blur. When I execute `fullpage` method on my container the blur disappears. If I don't turn on fullpage - the blur stays. But I don't know why and how fullpage.js screws it up...

Answer (score 0):

The filter CSS property lets you apply graphical effects like blurring or color shifting to an element. Filters are commonly used to adjust the rendering of images, backgrounds, and borders.

Included in the CSS standard are several functions that achieve predefined effects. You can also reference an SVG filter with a URL to an SVG filter element.

For more details you can visit this link 
[MDN WEB DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Comment: Thanks, although I don't know why you are explaining me what a filter is, I know what it does ;)